# Cleric/Archer spell casting

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric

As a beginner to dnd i have a couple of specific questions.

The first one pertains to an amulet vs emblem, i assume they're the same and its ultimately up to preference but i wanted to double check. Is there any difference between them?

The next one is in regards to casting spells as a cleric. I wanted to just wear the amulet on a chain around my neck and use my bow with my two free hands so i would be of use to the party besides just healing constantly. However wouldn't i need another free hand to cast the spells?  For example: an ally is hurt and i reach up and grab my amulet to cast cure wounds while holding my bow in the other. Would i be able to direct my spell to that ally with my bow in the other hand?(i assume it would be the same for an attack on an enemy)

I am a light domain cleric btw

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site.  Please take the [tour] and have a look  around.  Our site has a one question per post policy, and it looks like you've asked a couple here.  I recommend you split your questions into separate posts, because as your question stands right now it will be closed as too broad.  Please visit the [help] page for more information.  Thanks!

Comment: By "amulet" or "emblem" are you referring to the holy symbol being used as a spell casting focus?

Answer (score 3):

A two-handed weapon only needs to be held in two hands when you're attacking with it. When you're casting a spell or performing any other one-handed action, you don't need to be holding the bow with two hands.

Answer (score 2):

Player's Handbook (PHB for short) p151 regarding Holy Symbols:

> A cleric or paladin can use a holy symbol as a spellcasting focus, as
>   described in chapter 10. To use the symbol in this way, the caster
>   must hold it in hand, wear it visibly, or bear it on a shield.

To cast the spell you need one hand free, so in your case the character would hold the bow in one hand while casting. The symbol just needs to be visible, which your description says it is.

As an aside, this rule says that you can cast a cleric spell with the symbol hidden, as long as you are holding it. Something for clerics of the trickery domain to consider, for instance.